# Why does using vertical orientation for my layered line plot not do anything?

Tags: plot, vega-lite, line-plot

If I change `horizontal` to `vertical` here, the axes don't switch:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "layer": [{
      "data": {"values": [
        {"x": 0.5, "y": 0},
        {"x": 1, "y": 1},
        {"x": 2, "y": 2}]},
      "mark": {"type": "line", "orient": "horizontal"},
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"field": "x", "type": "quantitative"},
        "y": {"field": "y", "type": "quantitative"},
        "color": {"datum": "a"}}
    }, {
      "data": {"values": [
        {"x": 1, "y": 0},
        {"x": 2, "y": 1},
        {"x": 2.5, "y": 2}]},
      "mark": {"type": "line", "orient": "horizontal"},
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"field": "x", "type": "quantitative"},
        "y": {"field": "y", "type": "quantitative"},
        "color": {"datum": "b"}}
    }
  ]
}
```

Why is that? How to get the x-axis and y-axis to switch places?

Answer (score 0):

It's also necessary to switch the "x" and "y" properties of "encoding":

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "layer": [{
      "data": {"values": [
        {"x": 0.5, "y": 0},
        {"x": 1, "y": 1},
        {"x": 2, "y": 2}]},
      "mark": {"type": "line", "orient": "vertical"},
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"field": "y", "type": "quantitative"},
        "y": {"field": "x", "type": "quantitative"},
        "color": {"datum": "a"}}
    }, {
      "data": {"values": [
        {"x": 1, "y": 0},
        {"x": 2, "y": 1},
        {"x": 2.5, "y": 2}]},
      "mark": {"type": "line", "orient": "vertical"},
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"field": "y", "type": "quantitative"},
        "y": {"field": "x", "type": "quantitative"},
        "color": {"datum": "b"}}
    }
  ]
}
```